# Devise before_action explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am having trouble understanding this line that gets automatically generated in the controller when I install Devise:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

I tried reading the documentation but I am unable to make sense of what it does. For example what does the `:set_post` symbol do? What is it part of?

Any explanations or resources where I can go for further reading would be appreciated.

Comment: It fires method named `set_post` before execution of `[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a controller like this:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end
   def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end
   def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

You see that in `show` and `edit` actions there is the same code, you're breaking the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, so to avoid code repetitions you set an action (method):

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

that will be performed before the actions that require that same code:

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

In the end you'll have a controller like this:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end
   def show
   end
   def edit          
   end

   private
      def set_post
         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

:set_post - a method at the end of the controller.

The device does not have anything to do with